# Why does a raising to the power of in excel give me an incorrect result?

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I have a formula which I am trying to replicate in excel but it is giving mean incorrect result.

The formula is:

> ((1.83 x 10-6) x 6

which should give `0.00001098`

My excel formula is:

```
((1.83^-6) x 6
```

and get the result of `0.15` - clearly a bit different!!

I thought that `^` was the correct way to do this.

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `N * 10-6` ?= `N^-6` ... are you sure????

Comment: I don't think you're using exponents properly...please review your syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula means that you calculate (1.83 to the power of -6) times 6.

What you want is the letter `E`, as in `=(1.83E-6)*6`

Comment: This looks like it will work :)  Moving on, I now have a formula with a cell reference `=(C4e10 * E9) however excel sees this a a typo - what is the syntax when there is a cell reference involved?

Comment: Try adding `1` before the `E` like `=(C4*1E10*E9)`

Answer (score 2):

### Write formula:

```
=((1.83*10^-6)*6)
```

---

**Your mistake is:**

```
=((1.83^-6)*6)
```

**Compare:**

True: `(1.83)*(10^-6)`

You write: `(1.83)^-6`